# Please welcome your new moderators!

Tags: discussion, moderators

I'm Pops, a Community Manager at Stack Exchange. Though it saddens me to say it, not just one but two of your existing moderators are stepping down for personal reasons. Over the past week and a half, I've been working on finding replacements, and I'm happy to announce that two avid Code Reviewers have answered the call to be your new pro tem mods:

[image: rolfl]
[image: 200_success]

Please join me in thanking codesparkle and sepp2k for their service and welcoming rolfl and 200_success!

Comment: Hopefully they both will "upgrade" from "pro tem" to "elected" before they earn [badge:constable]!

Comment: congrat @ rolfl and @ 200_success

Answer (score 21):

It makes *me* happy to say it: Congratulations, @rolfl and @200_success.

I really couldn't come up with any better names for moderator positions! You have my full support!

Well done, Community Managers at Stack Exchange.

Comment: Not going to post a duplicate answer, this one is reading my mind :)

Comment: Not going to duplicate either! But I must add that they're both Canadians!

Comment: maybe they will rub off on us, eh?

Comment: Congrats 200_success and rolfl

Answer (score 16):

Congratulations! I'm sure you two will be, like, awesome moderators!

Answer (score 14):

Congratulations to rolfl and 200_success!

I'm sorry to say I no longer have enough time to actively help moderate Code Review, but it has been amazing to watch all the community-driven initiatives to expedite graduation.
I am sticking around as a regular visitor of the site and I hope to contribute the occasional review.

Comment: Thank you for your service. :-) It's nice to hear that you'll still be around to contribute to the site.  The new moderators and I will continue to help CR advance towards graduation.