# 2014: What a ride!

Tags: discussion, fun

Here we are, with another year [almost] behind us. 2014 has been very, very special on Code Review, and that has been completely because of **you**.

2014 was ...glittering. We've put Code Review on the Stack Exchange map; in 2015, we're entering the big league of full-grown, graduated sites.

What events made 2014 a year to remember on CR?

Comment: Shall we do Best of Code Review 2014 properly, using the [same process as last year](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1320/9357)?

Comment: Best of Code Review FTW

Comment: @200_success I liked LY's *Best Of*, but I find it missed an educative aspect, not to mention the "Santax" you paid.. I'd want to nominate an edit that turned an off-topic question into a successful hot network question; with last year's format it wouldn't be possible... so I figured we could do both ways..

Comment: Why not have a category for Best Edit? As for the "Santax" — ho ho ho! I don't mind spending some points for a worthy cause.

Comment: @200_success perfect then - edited :)

Comment: [Best of Code Review 2014](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3859/best-of-code-review-2014-categories-discussion/3861) is on!

Answer (score 31):

## Code Review Graduated

- Official SE "Decision made" date: **Sept 22 2014**
- Announcement ["Going Public" date](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/code-review-se-is-graduating): **Sept 30, 2014**
- Graduation applied (Privs/Colours) date: **T.B.D.**

In large part thanks to significant, sustained, and far-reaching growth (image taken at around that time):

[image: Code Review Growth]

Answer (score 24):

### Not just one, but two open source projects were born in the 2nd Monitor.

We don't just review code around here. We *write it too*.

A lot of the regulars in the 2nd Monitor began working on a card game called [Cardshifter](https://github.com/Cardshifter/Cardshifter) in August. [A dedicated chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16134/tcg-creation) was created. It is sourced using Java 8 and related technologies.

Over in the [VBA chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba), we began working on an [ambitious project to bring VBA's IDE into this century.](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck) This was also born out of a strong desire for a good Unit Testing framework for VBA.

Both projects are very active and we have Code Review to thank for bringing the contributors together.

Comment: Is there a website showing how to play Cardshifter or explaining what the game is? I'm interested in playing it, but I'm not adventurous enough to just download the client without having some idea what the game it.

Comment: @Kevin here's a link to the [Game Rules](https://github.com/Cardshifter/Cardshifter/wiki/Game-Rules), but you might just want to stop by chat and talk to the devs.

Comment: @Kevin It's still under construction, but it is similar to Hearthstone. You're welcome to [join our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16134/tcg-creation) and talk to the developers!

Comment: Cardshifter now has a wiki page on [How To Play](https://github.com/Cardshifter/Cardshifter/wiki/How-to-play-Cardshifter). The web client is easiest to use - just browse to http://play.cardshifter.com/!

Answer (score 20):

## FizzBuzz Attack!

When [Jamal](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22222) posted [his first Java question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56708), a [fizzbuzz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fizzbuzz), something happened in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595), and then July saw a [fizzbuzz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fizzbuzz) implementation in just about every programming language out there...

The invasion continued through August, and in September a [Mug](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788) went on to [smoke the manual](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1953/23788) and created the [lolcode](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lolcode) tag after implementing [fizzbuzz in LOLCODE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/61416/23788). That was fun and all, and resulted in a discussion about [reviewing esoteric languages](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2409/23788), where all points of view were expressed and debated.

As a result of all this, **Code Review has 55 [fizzbuzz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fizzbuzz) questions** as of this writing.

**...and [40 were asked in 2014](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfizzbuzz%5D+created%3A2014+is%3Aquestion)...** [and 31 of them followed Jamal's post in July](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bfizzbuzz%5d%20created%3a2014-07..%20is%3aquestion).

Comment: And in 2015 we're all hoping to see an implementation written in [Shakespeare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare_%28programming_language%29) (not really)

Comment: In 2015 we're all hoping to see more [tag:brainfuck] code!

Comment: 144 fizzbuzz now, wow

Answer (score 19):

## New - *active* - Moderators

Back in March, [Code Review got two new moderators](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1679/please-welcome-your-new-moderators) that turned out to be very active. It has always been easy to get in contact with them in our chatroom, and they have done a great job in contacting users through chat whenever something was up.

Answer (score 12):

## MathJax and Stack Snippets

Two new technologies introduced this year have transformed the face of Code Review.

At the request of @VedranŠego, and with broad support from the CR community, we gathered enough evidence to convince Stack Exchange staff of the benefits of MathJax to the site.  On April 7, [MathJax was enabled](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1708/9357)!

In contrast to the hard work we had to do to earn MathJax, the Stack Snippets feature came as a bit of a present.  [In August](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2392/9357), Stack Exchange developers informed us of the new feature that they had developed.  It didn't take much argument to convince them that piloting a feature on a beta site was a good idea.

Rather than naming specific posts here that have made good use of MathJax and Stack Snippets, I have proposed them as categories for [Best of Code Review 2014](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3859/9357), so that we can all participate in picking out the best posts.

Comment: There have been some pretty good Snippets, but I think I have a pretty good idea which post is going to win that category. =;)-