# Best of Code Review 2014

Tags: discussion, fun, best-of

As 2014 comes to an end, let's kick off Best of Code Review 2014!

All Code Review users will be invited to nominate (link to) the best questions and answers from this year, and showcase them as examples of what great CR questions and answers should look like.  Prizes in the form of bounties will be awarded wherever feasible.

---

### Conclusion

The winners of Best of Code Review 2014 are:

- **Lots of Laughs (best use of humor):**

  - @RubberDuck on [A practical example of evenly distributing n lists into a single list](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/59707), with 13 meta votes
  - @SimonAndréForsberg on ['Team Split' problem](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45150), with 13 meta votes

  I've awarded 100 points each to @RubberDuck and @SimonAndréForsberg.
- **Exterminator (answer that points out the most obscure bug):**

  - @Edward on [Calculating the harmonic average](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/71663), with 8 meta votes

  I've awarded 150 points to @Edward for the winning answer.
- **Night and Day (most dramatic improvement):**

  - @200_success on @KristoferGisslén's [Complex query to count votes with a redistribution system](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/54243), with 4 meta votes

  I've awarded 100 points to @KristoferGisslén for the question.
- **Best Title:**

  - @rolfl's title [Regularity in the "Rusty Towel of Mutual understanding"](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/64402) on @Nit's question (originally called *Generating random item names*), with 13 meta votes

  I've awarded 100 points to @rolfl for the edit.

I hope that Best of Code Review 2014 has helped to showcase contributions from our members — not just the winners, but the other nominees as well.  Let's do this again next year!

Comment: Are meta-posts also nominable?

Comment: @Vogel612 Good titles and humor are desirable in meta posts too. Let's allow them.

Answer (score 34):

**[Best of Code Review 2014 - Lots of Laughs category](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3881/23788):** Answer that makes the best use of humor to illustrate a point.

Comment: Oh, I like this!

Comment: What about funny questions and comments? I propose that we nominate them, but they wouldn't be eligible for a prize.

Answer (score 30):

**[Best of Code Review 2014 - Exterminator category](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3882/23788):** Answer that points out the most interesting obscure bug in the original code

Answer (score 26):

**[Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Title category](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3883/23788):** The question with the best title. (If the title was later added by someone else, be sure to credit the user who edited the title.)

Comment: There's been so many good (and horrible) titles this year so this one is a must have!

Answer (score 25):

**[Best of Code Review 2014 - Night and Day category](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3890/9357):** The most dramatic improvement (nominate both the question with the most hopeless code and the answer that cleans it up the best)

Answer (score 20):

**Not As Easy As It Looks category:** Question that superficially appears simple but turns out to be more difficult than expected

Answer (score 19):

**Diplomat category:** Tough advice in an answer, delivered in the most tactful manner

Answer (score 18):

**Jamalizer* Award category**, for question edits that turned bad questions into good ones.

*[see *Jamalized*](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1675/23788)

Comment: For fairness, should all entries exclude my own?  You can also provide the meme link for clarification.

Comment: @Jamal I don't think there is any reason why you shouldn't be eligible to win. Maybe you would want to sponsor this prize, though.

Comment: @200_success: I just mentioned that because mine might be better than most, but that might not be the case.  But yeah, if I don't win, then I'm okay with awarding that prize.  I'm just unsure about one thing: would the bounty have to be awarded to some post by that editor, not the author?

Comment: I think the prize should be awarded to the editor, not the original author. The editor must also have posted an answer somewhere to be eligible to claim a prize.

Comment: @200_success: Sounds good.  We'll specify that if this category is chosen.

Comment: I think it's more to showcase great edits than to earn anyone "santax" rep; I suggest  nominees can be unrestricted (including Jamal's edits), and *if applicable*, that an answer gets linked to, for a prize to be claimed.. but I wouldn't make it obligatory; there are certainly great edits that went without an answer on the edited question, worthy of a nomination in this category.

Answer (score 16):

**Gordian Knot Untied category:** Most justified advice in an answer for taking a completely different approach from the code in the original question

Answer (score 16):

**Rags to Riches category:** The [rags-to-riches](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rags-to-riches) question that took the worst original code and made it shine like a polished gem

Answer (score 14):

**Stack Snippets category:** The question, answer, or edit that makes the best use of Stack Snippets

Comment: Considering how nice this feature has been this year, we gotta have this category!

Answer (score 13):

**MathJax category:** Question, answer, or edit that makes the best use of MathJax

Answer (score 9):

**Best Newcomer (Answer) category:** Best answer by a user who wasn't a member yet before 2014.

Answer (score 9):

**Best Newcomer (Question) category:** Best question by a user who wasn't a member yet before 2014.