# Best of Code Review 2014 - Lots of Laughs category

Tags: discussion, answers, fun, best-of

Please post your nominations for the [Best of Code Review 2014 - Lots of Laughs](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3871/23788) category.

> *Answer that makes the best use of humor to illustrate a point.*

In your nomination post, please make sure to include a link to the nominated answer, as well as a short explanation of what makes that post worthy of being nominated in this category, and why it should win over the others.

---

<sub>**Small characters at the bottom:**
Only one nomination per post, nominated answers must have a creation date in 2014, downvotes don't count, and Santa reserves the right to award the top-voted nominee a special bounty as a token of appreciation on behalf of the Code Review community.</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [Rubberduck on "A practical example of evenly distributing n lists into a single list"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/59707/41243)

> One word.... ***VELOCIRAPTORS***.
>
> [image: xkcd GoTo]
>
> You seem like a nice guy, I don't want the raptors to get you...

The answer goes on to mention "The dreaded GoTo" and "Velociraptors" several times.

Comment: I hate to say it, but I habitually +1 anything with an XKCD reference... Sooooo... +1.

Comment: Shouldn't XKCD be the ones to get the bounty if this would win?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I would be ecstatic to have Randall Monroe amount our ranks.

Answer (score 13):

## [Simon on 'Team Split' problem](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45150/31562)

One word:

> ## Rewafadhabihlgdity

Okay, maybe "one" more word.

> Dontyoufinditabithardtoreadtext/codethatdoesntcontainanyspacesandappropriatepunctuation?

These two "words" make the point clear about how readable the code was, and why it is good to use spacing.

Answer (score 12):

I just realized that [meta answers were eligible for nomination too](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3859/best-of-code-review-2014-now-accepting-nominations#comment8289_3859), so...

## [Mat's Mug on Can I put my code on a third party site and link to the site in my question?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1308/41243)

Why? Because cats and the internet are like peas and carrots and I can't think of anything that could possibly drive home the reason we can't rely on external links for content than this.

> [image: Pastebin.com is under heavy load right now. Should be back online soon.]

Comment: upvoted, cuz catz.

Answer (score 9):

### Comment by 200_success on [Optimizing nested loop for an array within a list](//codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63876/optimizing-nested-loop-for-an-array-within-a-list?noredirect=1#comment116801_63876)

Funny that @hamsaya chose to use `birds` as a hypothetical identifier when asking an off-topic question about nesting.

> But really, we need to know the type of birds you are talking about to know what kind of nesting is appropriate. –  200_success♦ Sep 25 '14 at 17:37

Comment: Funny as it is, I don't think this qualifies. It's not an *answer*. I do think it should stay here though because reasons.

Comment: @RubberDuck It is acknowledged that [comments  are not eligible to win](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3859/best-of-code-review-2014-now-accepting-nominations?noredirect=1#comment8272_3871).

Answer (score 8):

### [200_success on Wow that's a big integer! What's its largest prime factor?](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/58254/9357)

> What a fascinating solution! It seems that for every smart decision you made, you also threw in a poor decision or two.

To which RubberDuck said, [a month later in chat](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17453028#17453028):

> This remains one of my favorite reviews. @200 cracks me up.

Comment: Still makes me laugh too. ++

Answer (score 7):

## [Zirak on "How do I make this Average Function better?"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/14107/41243)

> And what happens if you get an empty array? You divide by zero, which is MADNESS!! MADNESS I TELL YOU!

The answer actually points out some pretty serious bugs and design flaws (i.e. ***madness***). I think it was a fantastic use of humor to really drive home the point.

Answer (score 7):

## [user50399 on "Numbers to words"](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/60862/9357)

> "Strone"?  What's a "strone"?  Oh… [of course](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strone)!

That sarcastic admonition against Hungarian notation made @RubberDuck laugh, at least.

> <sub>+1 for making me laugh. [Kill the Hungarian Notation with fire!](http://www.reactiongifs.us/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/kill_it_with_fire.gif) —  RubberDuck Aug 23 '14 at 12:00</sub>