# Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Title category

Tags: discussion, fun, questions, titles, best-of

Please post your nominations for the [Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Title](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3868/23788) category.

> *The question with the best title.*

In your nomination post, please make sure to include a link to the **revision of the question** (from the revision history) that introduced the nominated title, as well as a short explanation of what makes that post worthy of being nominated in this category, and why it should win over the others.

---

<sub>**Small characters at the bottom:**
Only one nomination per post, nominated questions must have a creation date in 2014, downvotes don't count, and Santa reserves the right to award the top-voted nominee a special bounty as a token of appreciation on behalf of the Code Review community. Since this is a question category, the author of the nominated revision must also have an answer *on the nominated question*, to qualify for a prize - note that a revision can be nominated regardless of whether or not the revision's author has an answer on that question.</sub>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> **[Regularity in the “Rusty Towel of Mutual understanding”](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/64402/3)**

Author: Rolfl (revision 3) | [answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/64409/23788)

This question also went to the *Hot Network Questions* and into the weekly CR newsletter the week it was posted. I think this was a great title because it's not only eye-catching and intriguing, it actually - believe it or not - says exactly what the post is about, and what the OP's main concern is. We need more titles like this!

Answer (score 8):

> **[KISS my... unit of work](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/63477/23788)**

Author: Mat's Mug (OP)

This question went to the *Hot Network Questions* and into the weekly CR newsletter the week it was posted. I think it was a great title because there's a touch of humor, and it still conveys what the post is about and what the OP's main concern is.

Comment: Beat me to it. That's okay. There's another one of yours I had in mind.

Answer (score 6):

> **[Aliens at the train](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/59486/29371)**

Author: [pimgd](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/49350/pimgd)
[Revision 8](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/59486/8)

it has more than 2k of views and had been in the hot networkquestions  too.

Comment: It should be noted that this question started off as off-topic - it was edited by a bunch of CR regulars, got reopened, and ended up as a hot network question. The title certainly played a major part in that question's success. Well done @pimgd!

Answer (score 6):

> **[If she floats then she is not a witch like we thought](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63708/if-she-floats-then-she-is-not-a-witch-like-we-thought)**

Author: [syb0rg](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/27623/syb0rg)

Comment: *([cough](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=17817528#17817528))*

Answer (score 5):

> **[Enter the Matrix](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67870/enter-the-matrix)**

Original Poster: [BlackHawk](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/36252/blackhawk)

Title Author ([Revision 3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/67870/3)): [Mat's Mug](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mats-mug) | [answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/67886/23788)

Because... ya know... puns.

Answer (score 4):

> **[Who's in the fellowship? When are Frodo, and the rest of the gang, together](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74543/whos-in-the-fellowship-when-are-frodo-and-the-rest-of-the-gang-together)**

Original Poster: [rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31503/rolfl)

In the Spirit of The Hobbit: BoFA... (also, when I saw this on the Hot Questions list, I thought it was from the movies/TV SE site...)

Comment: I have to say, this one undoubtedly wins the "most creative fizzbuzz implementation" category!

Answer (score 3):

> **[Everyone loves Fibonacci](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54769/everyone-loves-fibonacci)**

Author: [Rubberduck](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/41243/rubberduck)

> This one **has** to be be nominated in the *Best Question Title* category! –  [Mat's Mug Jun 20 at 11:36](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54769/everyone-loves-fibonacci#comment95785_54769)

Answer (score 3):

> **[We'll be counting stars](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/48258/23788)**

Author: [Simon André Forsberg](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31562)

This one was unfortunately forgotten. But it's a great example of a good CR title.