# How can I ask interesting questions as a beginner?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Here at Code Review, we, the reviewers volunteering our time, are deciding to use our time to focus on improving something we found on this site. Because of this, questions must be interesting. It is easy to ask interesting questions if you are 'medium/intermediate'. If I am just learning the basic syntax and concepts of a new programming language, how can I ask an interesting question that people will be happy reviewing?

Comment: How closely do you think this question is related to: [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) ?

Comment: @rolfl I read the answer to the other question. The problem is with this phrase: _Give as much relevant background to your code as you can. Make it both concise and complete (it can be done). Flowery and 'chummy' language does not help. Stick to the facts._ What if the code has no background? What if it is some FizzBuzz-like problem, where I am just learning basic sintax?

Comment: @Caridorc I would suggest taking a look at well received questions in the [tag:beginner] and [tag:fizz-buzz] questions. Perhaps add a relevant language tag to your search when looking at [beginner]. Reading some well received questions would be a good start to learning what makes those good questions.

Comment: @RubberDuck thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. You're also free to stop by [the 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) anytime if you're concerned about a question you're about to ask. There's a group of regulars there who would be happy to answer questions about it. Of course, meta is always an option too. =)

Comment: A snazzy question title helps too ^_^

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the best things you can do is prepare a simple project that actually solves many real-life problems, such as a guess-the-number game.  This project requires variable assignment, conditionals, and loops, and can also use methods/functions (if applicable to the language), a GUI, and other more advanced concepts that you may wish to include.  This will be on topic for a code review, you will learn a lot writing the project (if it is a first for the language), and the review will also teach you a lot about the language and best practices.

One common, but beginner-simple, program written here is FizzBuzz.  I'm not really recommending you write more after last year's [FizzBuzz invasion](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3826/41243), but these questions garnered many good reviews that are helpful for learning languages, and other simple questions can do the same.

Comment: +1 for *a simple project that actually solves many real-life problems, such as a guess-the-number game.*